# D3 Chaining Animations using a for loop

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an array with below elements:

```
var parentArray = [ [[1, 0.5], [2, 0.9], [3, 0.6]], [[1, 0.2], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.4]], [[1, 0.1], [2, 0.5], [3, 0.7]], [[1, 0.6], [2, 0.9], [3, 0.3]], [[1, 0.3], [2, 0.7], [3, 0.6]]];
```

To create a chained animation using `d3.js` I have written the below code:

```
var gg = main.append("svg:g");
        gg.selectAll("scatter-dots")
            .data(parentArray)
            .enter().append("svg:circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[0][1]); } )
                .attr("cy", function (d,i) { return y(i); } )
                .attr("r", 8)
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[1][1]); } )
                .transition()
                .duration(2000)
                .attr("cx", function (d,i) { return x(d[2][1]); } );
```

I have hard coded the values `d[0][1]`, `d[1][1]`, `d[2][1]` instead of using a loop. Please help me in writing the above code using a loop by using `d[i][1]` where `i > 1` and `i < parentArray.length`.

This question is similar to - [D3 Chaining Animations with a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120435/d3-chaining-animations-with-a-for-loop). But, the answers are not solving my problem.

For the complete code Please visit here - http://jsfiddle.net/JR6K9/101/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
  //make a global variable
var index = 0;
doTransition();//call transition on all circles

function doTransition() {
  d3.selectAll("circle").transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
      return x(d[index][1]);
    }).each("end", function(d, i) {
      if (i == parentArray.length -1) {//when last circle transition is completed
        index++;//increment index
        if (index > 2)//the data array has length of 2
          return;
        doTransition();//do the transition
      }
    });

}
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/ojoxhm4d/).

Comment: Instead of using this hard coded condition - `if (index > 2)` I guess we can use `if (index > parentArray[1].length - 1)` (Assuming all the arrays inside parentArray are equal in length)

Comment: yep that would make it better!